# Java: How to arrange 2-D arrays by a specific column when there are nulls in it

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have this array: called String [][]datos= new String [99999][3]; and I have to fill in some data as if it were a school. The first column, is the id number of a student, the second is the name, and the third is the amount of money he has to pay to a school. As you may notice, by asking the id number first you can arrange them by the first column (id numbers). The problem is I want to arrange it by second or third column too and I can't find a way to do it without having NullPointerException because of the nulls that represent id numbers not filled in yet. Can someone help me by giving me a way to sort them correctly?
This is were I ask for the id number:

```
System.out.println("Ingrese datos del alumno (apellido y nombre)");
                    datos[matricula][1]=in.readLine();
                    datos[matricula][0]=Integer.toString(matricula);
```

Here I tell them that the id number is already used.

```
if(datos[matricula][0]!=null){
     System.out.println("\n\nERROR.\nEsa matricula ya existe");
}

  //Here I tell them to add the name:

else if(datos[matricula][0]==null){
    System.out.println("Ingrese datos del alumno (apellido y nombre)");
    datos[matricula][1]=in.readLine();
    datos[matricula][0]=Integer.toString(matricula);
                                                   }
```

then i send it to a method called reportes, where i will show the information. 
I used this code to just show them because they are arranged by the id number.

```
    for(int i=0;i<=datos.length-1;i++){
        if(datos[i][0]!=null){System.out.println(datos[i][0]+"\t\t\t"+datos[i][1]+"\t\t\t"+datos[i][2]);
     }
```

Comment: you can initiate them to empty string, so you wont have issues with null.

Comment: how do i do that? Do I have to add a "" in every space of the string that isn't used?

Comment: based on your update, do you really need to use arrays?, specifically String [][]datos= new String [99999][3] ?

Comment: yes, it is something they asked for as an assignment. Well, now that I think. They asked for arrays, but not specifically that way. If there is a better way to do it, I am free to any improvements as long as I still use arrays.

Comment: you might solve that issue, if at the beginning of your program you ask for total number of students first, that way you dont have to do: String [][]datos= new String [99999][3];  and so something like: 
String [][]datos= new String [TotalStudents][3]; , this will get rid of your null problems

Comment: yeah, that is the reason I did a string as big as that. I can't ask for the number.

Comment: @E.Rojas you can simply fill null fields by specific characters(e.g , '-' , '?'), thereby you won't get "NullPointerException". If you want to sort your information by other parameters, then you have to consider specific parameters to base your sorting method on them. For example if you want to sort your students by their family names alphabetically, then you have to consider the priority of each alphabet. for such purposes you need to simply use switch - case syntax. Let me notice that this website is not for solving home works. please check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @E.Rojas Must you use 2D array to store your stuff? If possible use a class instead. Many newbies use 2D array for the wrong purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As luisluix said you could initiate all the strings inside your matrix with the empty String value ("").
This is a sample:

```
for(int r = 0; r < 99999; r ++)
{
  for (int c = 0; c < 3; c ++)
  {
    datos[r][c] = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: and instead of null, check for empty string:
datos[matricula][0]!="", when checking if there is no info